# How to edit a file in Visual Studio from an FTP site?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ftp, visual-studio-2013

I am having trouble opening file from an FTP site in Visual Studio.  I do the following:

1. File/Open
2. Type in the ftp.foo.com, Enter
3. Type in credentials (tell it to remember them) into a dialog box that comes up.
4. Navigate to a file (called orientation.htm), select it, press Open
5. Then I get this error.

[image]

Am I missing something simple here?  Fails on both VS2012 and VS2013.

Comment: Am I missing something here? FTP is "File Transfer Protocol". The typical way to edit files for a web site is to download it to your local machine, edit it locally, and then upload it to the site again. (Actually, it's typically "Create the file locally, upload it to the web site. When changes are needed, edit the local copy and upload the modifications to the web site.")

Comment: @KenWhite At some point in the past this was a feature...that u could simply edit a file straight from the ftp site.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you would ever want to do that (even if it were possible, which I'm not convinced was ever the case), especially considering the need for the code editor to actually have the file in local memory in order to edit it in the first place. This doesn't seem to be something that would ever logically or intelligently have been a "feature". As I said, FTP is intended to be a file transfer protocol (uploading/downloading files), not a virtual desktop channel.

Comment: @KenWhite The purpose is convenience. Instead of having to download the file, edit, then upload...you just simply edit it as it were local.  Windows allows you to add an FTP site as Network Place - presumably for that purpose.  There is a product out there called NetDrive that does what I want, but I'd rather do it natively in Windows.

Comment: Um, no. The editor *still has to download the file to it's buffer*. You're adding the additional overhead of transferring the file back and forth (perhaps repeatedly) every time you save changes. Adding an FTP site as a network place does not mean the file is not transferred locally when you modify it - it is *always* transferred. You're just making the editing process slower (because of transfer overhead).

Comment: @KenWhite I understand all that and agree with you.  The only thing I am speaking off is convenience.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the product and should be filed to http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/